# Elasticsearch and Drupal : how to add filter lowercase and asciifolding

Tags: elasticsearch, drupal-7

I created an index in Drupal, and my queries works.
Now I try to add filters lowercase and asciifolding in the elasticsearch.yml file, but unsuccessfully:

I add these lines :

```
index:
 analysis:
  analyzer:
   default:
    filter : [standard, lowercase, asciifolding]
```

I have an error : IndexCreationException: [myindex] failed to create index.
But 'myindex' already exist, I just try to add filters to this existing index.

How I can add these filters so that the indexation is correct for me?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get this exception is because it's not possible to update the settings of an index by calling the general create index endpoint. In order to update analyzers you will have to call the '_settings' endpoint.

I've made a small example for you on how to do this:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "new_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "new_analyzer",
  "text": "NoLowercasse"
}

POST test/_close

PUT test/_settings
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "new_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "asciifolding",
          "lowercase"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_open

GET test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "new_analyzer",
  "text": "LowerCaseAdded"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "lowercaseadded",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see that after the second analysis, the lowercase filter is being applied. The reason that you have to close your index is because it needs to rebuild the analyzer. You will notice that the new analyzer won't work as expected since the previously added documents weren't indexed with this analyzer, but rather the one without the asciifolding and lowercase.
In order to fix this, you'll have to rebuild your index (with the [Reindex-API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) for example)

Hope this helps!

**Edit**: I maybe was a bit too quick in responding, as this is not a Drupal-Elastic solution, but it might point you in the right direction. To be honest I'm not familiar with running ES in combination with Drupal.

Comment: Thank you very much Byron :) Indeed it is the right direction, but I do not manage to apply it for drupal, at the moment ...

Comment: I'll keep checking